# Any way in C# to make the compiler flag constructors that don't call the base class constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

Is there any setting that will make the C# compiler flag derived class constructors that don't call the base class constructor?  I get bit by this one fairly often, especially with derived classes that have multiple constructors.

Comment: No, there is no such flag.Perhaps, the roslyn can do this.

Comment: What do you mean? The base class's default constructor will *always* be called. If the default constructor doesnt exist, the compiler will force you to call some other constructor.

Comment: What happens if you set the base class default constructor to private?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Default constructors are always public.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Its not possible according to the c# specs to not call the base constructor.

Comment: In what case do you "get bit"? An example would help clarify.

Comment: @Andy There are pathological cases. For example in `class A { } class B : A { public B() : this(1) { } public B(int i) : this() { } }` the class `B` never calls a base class constructor (in fact even if all `A`'s constructors are private it still compiles). Of course, the program will blow the stack upon calling `new B()`, so a warning isn't very useful.

Answer (score 7):

A class constructor in C# will always call the base class constructor (except for object).  The call may not be explicit in the user code but it will exist in the emitted IL.  This is only true for the parameter less constructor though, calls to constructors with parameters must be explicitly done.

There is no way to force derived types to explicitly call the base type parameter less constructor because calling it implicitly is allowed by the language.  You can however force them to call *a* base class constructor by making the parameter less constructor private

```
abstract class Parent { 
  private Parent() { } 

  // Base classes will be forced to explicitly call this one
  protected Parent(/* some parameter */) {  } 
}
```

Comment: Actually you don't need the private constructor here. The compiler won't emit a default constructor if there are any explicit constructors.